# Can I add custom properties to TortoiseSVN's list of properties in Add Properties dialog?

Tags: svn, properties, tortoisesvn

Our team is using some user-defined properties on our SVN repository. When I go to add a property to a file using TortoiseSVN, I right-click on the file and choose `TortoiseSVN / Properties`. I then click the `New...` button and get the `Add Properties` dialog. At the top of this dialog is a drop-down list of pre-defined properties labeled `Property name:`. The list includes properties such as `svn:needs-lock`, `svn:eol-style`, etc.

Is there a way I can add a couple of my own custom properties to this list? I am using TortoiseSVN 1.6.2.

I've googled this, and saw a proposed patch on the TortoiseSVN mailing list, but to my knowledge it hasn't been implemented. Thanks.

Edit: I know I can manually type my custom properties into that box, but I'd like them to be saved for next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the properties `tsvn:userfileproperties` and `tsvn:userdirproperties` on a parent directory to customize the list of properties.

Comment: Thanks, I must have missed these properties!! They have been there a while it looks like.

Comment: This things are setup from the server side right? Cannot do it on client?