# Questions Using SVN as Document Control System

Tags: windows, svn, version-control, document-versioning

I am looking at a way to do better document control for a document library at my work consisting of SOPs, forms, etc. (Mostly Microsoft Word files.) As far as actual changes to documents, I am contemplating setting up a SVN repository to handle the actual revisions to the documents and allowing for the most recent version to be at the forefront, however there are some other capabilities that I either 1) don’t know if they exist or 2) don’t know how to setup. Here are my questions:

1. I know there is Apache SVN, can I customize the design of how folders and files appear on the web page?
2. There are certain documents that need to be re-visited on a bi-yearly schedule etc, is there a way to easily flag these documents to be reviewed?
3. What is the best way to share an SVN repository amongst several people over a Windows network?

I have searched online but have not found any good resources that I can understand.

Answer (score 2):

> can I customize the design of how folders and files appear on the web page?

Yes, to some degree. I can't recall output of "naked" Apache in repository, but you have at least two choices for decorating repository (p.3 noted): [VisialSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/), in which you can change according to your needs svnindex.xsl

```
<!-- A sample XML transformation style sheet for displaying the Subversion
  directory listing that is generated by mod_dav_svn when the "SVNIndexXSLT"
  directive is used. -->
```

or install one additional level, PHP-based [WebSVN](http://www.websvn.info/) (or any other repository-browser), which have embedded templating

> There are certain documents that need to be re-visited on a bi-yearly schedule etc

I can't see any native ready-to-use tools in Subversion for this job, but for any object in repository date of last revision exist and it's easy (so-so) accessible information

> What is the best way to share an SVN repository amongst several people over a Windows network?

"Best" is always subject of <strike>flamewars</strike>discussion and debate, but you (for Windows world) have usual choice: svnserver of http-server (where httpd-based solution can be CollabSVN, UberSVN, VisualSVN Server /even Enrerprise Edition/ or pure Apache with web-frontend) for network access, where any solution have both "pro" et "contra". From my POV, VisualSVN Server Community edition have lowest TCO

Answer (score 1):

Since you're on Windows, [Visual SVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/) and [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.net/) are two free pieces of software that will get the job done.

We've made TortoiseSVN available to some of our end users and they've learned how to use it very quickly.

I wonder if you can use custom properties in SVN to flag documents for review? Maybe this related question will help: [Can I add custom properties to TortoiseSVN's list of properties in Add Properties dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150800/can-i-add-custom-properties-to-tortoisesvns-list-of-properties-in-add-propertie)

Tagging may also be useful; it could identify the last version of a document that was reviewed perhaps?

Answer (score -1):

SVN could work, but it's not designed for documents, it's designed for source code.

IMO you are trying to solve a problem with the wrong tool. What you really need is a Document Version Control tool, and there are some out there.

For one there is TeamForge (by CollabNet - SVN project founders) that will keep track of your document versions, manage reviews, and can easily hook into MS Office.

See more:
http://www.collab.net/products/teamforge/capabilities (Click on "Documents")

To try it for free:
https://app.cloudforge.com/trial_signup/new/

(Disclaimer: I do work for CollabNet)